# Flutter: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

Tags: flutter, textfield, inputconnection

I'm trying to retrieve the user input inside a TextField title so it can be passed to a function called  `void _filterList(value)`.
However, everytime I put some text this errors appear:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7715): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7715): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7715): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7715): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7715): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7715): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

This is my code:

```
List filteredlist = [];
List entries = [];
bool isSearching = false;

getCountries() async {
  var response =
    await Dio().get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/regionalbloc/eu');
return response.data;
}

@override
void initState() {
getCountries().then((data) {
  setState(() {
    entries = filteredlist = data;
  });
});
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      title: !isSearching
          ? Text('All EU Countries')
          : TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                _filterList(value);
              },
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
                hintText: "Search Here",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              )),
      actions: <Widget>[
        isSearching
            ? IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    this.isSearching = false;
                    filteredlist = entries;
                  });
                },
              )
            : IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    this.isSearching = true;
                  });
                })
      ],
    ),
    body: _buildList());
}
```

This is my function:

```
void _filterList(value) {
setState(() {
  filteredlist = entries.where(
      (entry) => entry['name'].toLoweCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()));
});
```

}

As far as I have undestrood there seems to be a problem with the keyboard, but I haven't figured out how to prevent it

Comment: What version of flutter are you using?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the controllers of the textfields are out of the build method and make sure the widget is statefull

Answer (score 2):

Known issue, tracked [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9471). Even this [sample code](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html#widgets.Form.1) gives warnings in android. No consensus on what's causing it.

> I did a little bit of digging. It looks like Android is generating these warnings because we are holding the InputConnection incorrectly in the Engine's TextInputPlugin. I haven't really figured out what we're doing wrong, though.

[source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9471#issuecomment-503342071)

Comment: I tend to get this warning when I type into any text field using my computer's keyboard rather than the on-screen mobile keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a TextEditingController and a FutureBuilder. Like this:

```
var searchController = TextEditingController();
var searchTerm = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    searchController.addListener(onSearch);
  }

 onSearch() {
    setState(() {
      searchTerm = searchController.text;
      updateList();
    });
  }

  Future updateList() async {
    return await getYourFilteredList(searchTerm);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(     
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
           TextField(controller: searchController),
            FutureBuilder(
      future: updateList(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData)
          return Expanded(
            child: _buildList(snapshot.data),
          );
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Note: I did not test this code, but I have written something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this in my project too. The cause of mine was I had a code invoking `MediaQuery.of(context).height` inside the build method of the class that returns the Scaffold Widget. I had to remove it and place it in the child widget class. For example:

Before I had...

````
```Class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
     //some code
     Widget build (BuildContext context) {
       double availableHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).height - statusBarHeight - appBarHeight;
       return Scaffold (//some code that passes availableHeight to a widget's [MyHomePageBody] constructor);
     }
}```
````

Now, I have...

````
```Class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
     //some code
     Widget build (BuildContext context) {
       
       return Scaffold (//some code);
     }
}

Class MyHomePageBody extends StatelessWidget {
     //some code
     Widget build (BuildContext context) {
       double availableHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).height - statusBarHeight - appBarHeight;
       return Container (//some code that uses availableHeight);
     }
}```
````

Some other fix that could work is to ensure your flutter channel is on the stable channel. If not, you can change the channel through the following command `flutter channel stable`

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11321#

Comment: Thank Ercross for this answer. You just save from suicide man!!!

Answer (score -1):

mediaQuery to get height, was inside build. It works, but here it caused error.

Code Before:-
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double _boxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2;
....

Code After:-
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double _boxHeight = 20;
....

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30013694)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).